# cacti + nagios + monit =?

Tags: nagios, monit, cacti

Currently I've got this trio configured, but I would like to have one solution, because configuring those 3 separately is a head ache time to time. First add service to monit, then to nagios and after that to snmpd processes and cacti.

So is there something combining functionality of Cacti, Nagios and Monit provided not as SaaS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) would be able to handle the Cacti and Nagios parts; it has both historical or performance graphing and live monitoring. However, it does not have a way to manage services out-of-the-box (last time I checked). It does have a very extensive API, though, so you could write a plugin that used the SSH credentials Zenoss can save per-host to log in and restart the appropriate service.

Answer (score 1):

I find that I need to use multiple solutions, depending on the environment. OpenNMS and Monit and Orca are my choices, for instance. OpenNMS and Orca can be substituted for any of the offerings out there, but I haven't found a direct replacement for Monit.

Comment: what's Orca all about? Google's just bringing up whales.

Comment: http://www.orcaware.com/orca/

Answer (score 1):

I use nagios for alerting and collectd for metric collection.
collectd then sends the data to graphite which stores the metrics.

As Dashboard I use the standard graphite web UI.

- http://graphite.wikidot.com/
- http://collectd.org/

It would be a lot of work to define all the dashboards and graphs by hand, so I found a [little python script](https://github.com/ClockworkNet/graphite-dashgen),
which generates dashboards and graphs automatically via cron.
I had to make some changes to it, but it works like a charm.

If you want to automate your nagios config you could use puppet's nagios type with exported resources: this is very powerful!

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_exported.html

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, but I personally recommend two

- [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com): ugly, powerful and similar to nagios approach.
- [Pandora FMS](http://pandorafms.com): nice graphs and reporting, most based on software agents. A different concept, more user friendly but you can miss some of the "nagios" magic configuration style.

There are others like Ganglia and Ximon, but are even older than nagios/cacti/munin